Regression: Lower and upper bounds
Suppose I want to predict an eta range for deliveries for an e-commerce/logistics service. More narrow ranges are perceived as more reliable. I'm curious about a loss function that can both 1/ accurately predict the range and 2/ generate as narrow a range as possible.
The design that I'm ideating over now is a regression model (could include but not constrained to deep neural networks) with two dimensional output. These parameters are [l, u] the lower bound and upper bound, respectively.
Suppose a given observation's ground truth observation is e (the eta.) The loss function that I propose is
$$\frac{1}{(u-e)(e-l)}$$
A few notes

If $u> e$, the first term is negative; but the second term will be positive.
If $e>l$, the second term is negative but the first is positive.
The reciprocal is taken to penalize overly broad ranges such as 60 days.
In theory, the bounds could be flipped where $l>u$. In such a case, these two negatives would cancel out yielding a large denominator and a small reward.

Where the goal is to maximize reward (as opposed to minimize loss.)
My questions are

Is the prediction of lower and upper bounds common? How is this normally done?
Am I missing some key way where this reward function backfires in a big way?


You may want to have a look at the Interval Score as a useful metric. The original derivation was proposed by Gneiting & Raftery, but there is a small blurb about it on Rob Hyndman's blog that you might find useful.

This is an interesting idea... which probably does not do what you want.
Whenever I see a new forecasting accuracy metric, I always test how it performs in very simple cases, by simulation. In the present case, I will predict iid $N(0,1)$ data, and for simplicity, I will only vary the lower endpoint $\ell$, taking the upper endpoint $u$ as $u=-\ell$, so we have symmetric prediction intervals - which makes sense for normally distributed data.
Specifically, I will generate 1,000,000 realizations, calculate the average score across these for $\ell=-3, -2.99, \dots,-0.01$ and plot these scores against $\ell$:

We get a huge variability, because of issues when the denominator is very small. For what it's worth, in this particular run $\ell=-0.02$ (and $u=0.02$) had the highest score... but changing the random number seed changes this dramatically. (This maximizer also happens to be right next to the score minimizer at $\ell=-0.03$.)
One other issue with your proposal is that it does not say and cannot include what a "good" prediction interval is. Sometimes you want a 90% PI. Sometimes a 50% PI. This does not enter into your KPI.

The key search term already popped up above: prediction-interval. You are looking for ways to evaluate PIs. There is indeed an established theory around this. As Nicholas Clark points out, much of it was discussed by Gneiting & Raftery (2007, JASA), although this really goes back at least to Winkler (1972). As Nicholas writes, the KPI of choice is the interval score, which is a consistent scoring function for symmetric prediction intervals with predefined coverage.
Actually, there are also other possible notions of PIs, with associated consistent KPIs; I give pointers to literature here. Interestingly enough, the shortest PI subject to given coverage, which you seem to be most interested in, is not elicitable among common classes of distributions (Brehmer & Gneiting, 2021; Fissler et al., 2021).

R code for the simulation:
set.seed(1) # for reproducibility
sims <- rnorm(1000000)
lower <- seq(-3, -0.01, by = 0.01)

scores <- sapply(lower, function(xx)
    mean(1 / ((-xx - sims) * (sims - xx))))

plot(lower, scores, type = "l", xlab = "Lower endpoint", ylab = "Mean score")

